# Get parameter from url text with Angular js

Tags: angularjs

i get it from backend this url and need to get from here only one parameter (games number)

https://www.example.com/#/?category=all&provider=all&game=3189&type=fun

How can i get game number (3189) in controller ?

## EDIT

its not $location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TO GET FROM URL

```
function GetParameter(parameterName) {
    var result = null;
    var tmp = [];
    var items = location.href.substr(1).split("&");
    for (var index = 0; index < items.length; index++) {
        tmp = items[index].split("=");
        if (tmp[0] === parameterName) result = decodeURIComponent(tmp[1]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

## TO GET FROM STRING

```
function GetParameterFromString(parameterName, url) {
    var result = null;
    var tmp = [];
    var items = url.split("&");
    for (var index = 0; index < items.length; index++) {
        tmp = items[index].split("=");
        if (tmp[0] === parameterName) result = decodeURIComponent(tmp[1]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

then you would call

```
var url = "example.com/#/?category=all&provider=all&game=3189&type=fun‌​";
var gameNumber = GetParameterFromString("game" url);
```

Comment: I have tested location.href.substr(1).split("&"); and it works. This answer shoudl give you what you want.

Comment: Its get parameter from URL of website , but in this case this link just text , not window location

Comment: var url = "example.com/#/?category=all&provider=all&game=3189&type=fun";

Comment: So i need get parameter from this url